# Do I need to awkward gcc option every time when compile with mysql.h?

Tags: mysql, c, api, gcc

When I use C Api for Mysql, I heard that I need to compile with gcc like
gcc $(mysql_config --cflags --libs) source.c 
but it is tired using this awkward whenever compile c file using mysql.

isn't there any good ways to compile like 
gcc source.c 
when using Mysql C api.

please help me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Learn how to write a small [Makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile), and you'll simply type `make` to compile your program.

Comment: And you could configure your editor (e.g. `emacs`) to have the compilation done by `make` with a single keystroke, e.g. by adding `(global-set-key [f12] 'recompile)` in your `~/.emacs` file

Answer (score 3):

Just set up a makefile to compile the scripts for you and use "make" instead of gcc each time.